# StreamBuilder silents unhandled exceptions. How to make it verbose?

Tags: flutter

`StreamBuilder` catches exceptions and calls builder with `snapshot.hasError == true`. It's ok in production but in dev I wanna be instantly notified about all exceptions.
How to force `StreamBuilder` to always print exceptions stacktrace in a console to prevent losing exceptions while developing. My current solution is to [create a wrapper](https://gist.github.com/fedotxxl/da439dffb8bcbd63315e5f1f76fac85f) widget. Do you have better ideas?

Comment: you cannot do that, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L137 - here `StreamBuilder` calls `Stream.listen()` method and passes to `onError`  just `Object error` so no `StackTrace` is used

Comment: Any solution? Same problem!

Comment: Check this one - https://gist.github.com/fedotxxl/da439dffb8bcbd63315e5f1f76fac85f

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy and paste the flutter class (F12 to navigate to it - go to implementation ). Change the name to MyStreamBuilder ;) and change the implementation as you wish.

.. 10 minutes later
Well after looking into the implementation I think a wrapper might be simpler and you keep connected to the original implementation. But for other classes which are lightweight, I would do the copy and go method.